# Selection rules for electronic transitions when noble gas atoms collide

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, atomic-physics, photon-emission

The selection rules of atoms that are alone are useful for determining whether there can be certain radiative transitions, or which transitions are more likely than others. For example, for small atomic number $Z$, there is $S_{tot}$ conservation, $l' = l, l+1, l-1$, and spatial parity flipping.

In the following, I'm considering colliding atoms, and I'm most interested in collisions of noble gas atoms and Helium in particular, so that there isn't a cross-section to form a molecule. I'm unsure whether the following is well-posed or to what extent it would depend on some sense of trajectories in the collision and so on, so please let me know if that's the case.

I am curious about whether electronic energy level transitions can be induced by atoms colliding with one another, and if so, whether there are selection rules associated with such collisions. For example, naively, if two Helium atoms with each of their spins in singlets collided, I would naively expect the final state to still have the spins in singlets. I would be very interested if the total spin of each the widely separated atoms could change. Further, I'm unsure about the changes $l$ could undergo, for example, and whether it would need to be conserved when there's a favored axis, the axis along which the particles collide.

Have these sort of $l$, spatial parity, and $S_{tot}$ selection rules been tabulated for collisions (in particular, for Helium)? If so, are there simple considerations like in the case of selection rules for atoms that motivate these selection rules?

Comment: Do you know how a HeNe laser works, and the role of collisions in exciting the Ne?

Comment: @JonCuster Roughly. For $1.15$ $\mu$m, I believe an electrical discharge excites He, and the He eventually relaxes into a $(1s)(2s)$ spin-triplet state which is quite close in energy to a Ne atom with one of the $(2p)^6$ electrons is excited to $4s$. Under collision between such an excited He atom and a ground state Ne atom, there is "energy transfer" and the Ne atom is excited. I think that rules out $l$ conservation, at least naively, since the Ne gains orbital angular momentum while the He's orbital momentum is unchanged. However, I'm unsure about the total spin of the excited Neon state.

Comment: In particular, if we had $S_{tot}$ conservation, then I would expect the relevant excited Neon state to be a spin triplet to ensure that $S_{tot}$ remains $1$ before and after the collision, since the ground states of He and Ne are invariant under rotation and are $S=0$. Thus, knowing whether or not the relevant excited Neon state is indeed a spin triplet would be useful for determining if $S_{tot}$ is conserved. Do you know whether this is the case?

Comment: @JonCuster Checking in about the HeNe discussion.